# Move all contrls inside form tag to div

Tags: jquery, css

This is the jQuery code that I am using to add the div to the page.

```
var div = jQuery(document.createElement('div'));
             div.attr('id', 'divFormWrapper');

             div.css({
                 "position": "absolute",
                 "top": 0,
                 "left": 0,
                 "width": "100%",
                 "height": "100%",
                 "overflow": "auto",
                 "-webkit-overflow-scrolling": "touch",
                 "background-color": "orange",
                 "border": "none",
                 "z-index": 0,
                 "display": "block"
             });

             jQuery('form').wrap(div);
```

It is adding the div tag before the form tag. I need it to add the div tag after the form tag.

```
 <div id="divFormWrapper" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow-x: auto; overflow-y: auto; background-color: red; border-top-style: none; border-right-style: none; border-bottom-style: none; border-left-style: none; border-width: initial; border-color: initial; border-image: initial; z-index: 0; display: block; ">
 <form name="Form1" method="post" id="Form1">

 controls.......
 </form>
 </div>
```

This is what I need it to do.

```
 <form name="Form1" method="post" id="Form1">
 <div id="divFormWrapper" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow-x: auto; overflow-y: auto; background-color: red; border-top-style: none; border-right-style: none; border-bottom-style: none; border-left-style: none; border-width: initial; border-color: initial; border-image: initial; z-index: 0; display: block; ">
 controls.......
 </div>
 </form>
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/wrapInner/

Comment: why not use jquery's `show()` and `hide()` and pre-define the div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `.wrap()` use [**`.wrapInner()`**](http://api.jquery.com/wrapInner/).

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/S3LkG/)**.

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery('form').children().wrapAll(div);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd modify it to use a more specific selector

```
$('#form1').children().wrapAll('<div id="divFormWrapper"/>`);
```